# Displaying leftwards arrow (U+2190) in regular text using xelatex

Tags: xetex, arrows, unicode

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{xltxtra} 
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text} 
\usepackage{gentium}
\setmainfont{Gentium Plus} 
\setromanfont[BoldFont={Gentium Basic Bold},ItalicFont={Gentium Italic}]{Gentium}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item ←Assamese   % Here the arrow (leftwards arrow, U+2190) doesn't get displayed in the PDF.
    \item $\leftarrow$ Assamese  % Here I get the desired arrow.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

I do not have any compilation errors.
The rest of the Unicode symbols get displayed perfectly. Is it possible to get the left arrow as it is in text without using the equivalent math `$\leftarrow$`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have contradictory statements in your preamble. Assuming you want to use Gentium Plus for upright and italic, with Gentium Basic for boldface, your preamble can be

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainfont{Gentium}[
  Upright Font=* Plus,
  BoldFont=* Basic Bold,
  ItalicFont=* Plus Italic
]

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item ←Assamese

\item $\leftarrow$ Assamese
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Version 5 of Gentium Plus has the glyph.

[image]

**Further notes**

- The package `inputenc` should not be used with XeLaTeX; usually also `fontenc` is unnecessary.
- IPA glyphs are already supported in Gentium, as far as I know, so `tipa` can be removed.
- `xltxtra` used to be recommended, but it's no longer.
- `Mapping=tex-text` is nowadays called `Ligatures=TeX`, but it's automatically loaded for the main font.
- The `gentium` package is for `pdflatex` and does nothing good with XeLaTeX.